# ReactJS: combine 2 JSON responses from get request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

So, I have this code that returns all of the data that can be retrieved from the endpoint. My endpoint has pagination: it only displays 10 datas per page. so my first endpoint: `Link + "api/materials/?page=" + page;` where `page = 1`, returns the first 10 data. then I have a second page so the for loop will now run `Link + "api/materials/?page=" + page;` where `page = 2` and will return a different set of datas. **What I want to happen** is that all the results from both endpoints will be displayed simultaneously, if I have 10 datas in my first endpoint, and 6 datas in my 2nd run of the endpoint, I want to be able to see 16 datas in my table. **What happens now** is that, when the loop starts and runs the first endpoint, it displays all the data from page 1, and then when it loops again and runs page 2, the data from page 1 will be replaced with page 2. I want to combine the data from page 1 and 2.

please help me.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Table } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import Link from './Link';
import axios from 'axios';
import _ from 'lodash';

class Material extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
        materials: []
    }
   }

   componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
    const total = localStorage.getItem('totalpage');
    var page;
    for (page = 1; page <= total ; page++) {
        const apiBaseUrl = Link + "api/materials/?page=" + page;

        const config = {
         headers: {
           'Authorization': "bearer " + token,
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         }
        }

        axios.get(apiBaseUrl, config)
         .then((response) => {
             console.log(response.data);
            this.setState({
             materials: response.data
           })
          })
    }

   }

    render() {
        const { materials } = this.state;

        let returndata = _.isEmpty(materials) ? [] : materials.data

        return (  
            <div className="ui container"> 
            <br />
            <br />
                <Table fixed>
                    <Table.Header>
                        <Table.Row>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>UUID</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>Title</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>Description</Table.HeaderCell>
                        </Table.Row>
                    </Table.Header>

                    <Table.Body>
                    {returndata.map((item, i) => {
                        return (
                        <Table.Row key = {i}>
                            <Table.Cell>{item.uuid}</Table.Cell>
                            <Table.Cell>{item.title}</Table.Cell>
                            <Table.Cell>{item.description}</Table.Cell>
                        </Table.Row>
                        )
                    })}
                    </Table.Body>
                </Table>
            </div>
      );
    }
  }
  export default Material;
```

Comment: [Promise.all....](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) I also strongly recommend seperating your concerns here, have a parent component that fetches the data pass it to a child component that is responsible for rendering it via props. Using state that way is a well known anti-pattern.

Comment: Are you sure you want to load all pages, no matter how many? A paged or infinite scrolling UX may be worth considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `.then` of `axios` with this

```
.then((response) => {
        let tempState = [...this.state.materials];
        tempState.push(response.data)
        this.setState({
         materials: tempState
       })
```

This will copy the state to another variable and push the new data into the new variable (`tempState`) and replace the state with `tempState` which now contains the previous state data and the new data

Comment: now it can't be rendered because it says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` :(

Comment: @Siraj yes I did, I commented on your answer

Comment: in the line `let returndata = _.isEmpty(materials) ? [] : materials.data` change `materials.data` to just `materials`

Comment: now it just renders, two blank rows in the table. :(

Comment: after `let returndata = _.isEmpty(materials) ? [] : materials.data` can you just log `returndata`?

Comment: This can set the materials out of order.

Comment: @WillCain what materials?

Comment: The state property is `materials`. OP didn't specify about ordering; it's just a warning.

Comment: @WillCain that is an array, how can it be out of order?

Comment: The array's entries could be misordered if the pages come back out of order. It's async, so you could get page 2 before page 1. May not matter; OP didn't specify.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your `componentDidMount` method. You can extend the current state object property instead of replacing it like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
  const total = localStorage.getItem('totalpage');
  var page;
  for (page = 1; page <= total ; page++) {
    const apiBaseUrl = Link + "api/materials/?page=" + page;

    const config = {
       headers: {
         'Authorization': "bearer " + token,
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       }
    }

    axios.get(apiBaseUrl, config)
     .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          materials: prevState.materials.concat(response.data)
        }));
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't get any errors but there is nothing being rendered in the table also.

Comment: @eibersji thought it was an object. Just updated to array. Should work now :)

Comment: @eibersji just do `materials: [...prevState.materials, response.data]`

Comment: This can set the materials out of order.

Comment: @WillCain yes and it also doesn’t handle duplicates but those considerations are out of scope of the problem

Comment: @André-JacquesdeBeer agreed, the OP didn't specify. It's just a warning.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're replacing the `materials` object in the state with the newly returned data.

> Call some function which will update your state.

```
axios.get(apiBaseUrl, config)
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    this.updateMaterials(response.data);
 })
```

> Now update your state in that function as
>   First retrieve the old list and then concat the new list in it, and then store it to your state.

```
updateMaterials = (data) => {
    let updatedList = this.state.materials.slice();
    updatedList = updatedList.concat(data);
    this.setState({materials: updatedList});
}
```

> Also remove `data` from materials.

change

```
let returndata = _.isEmpty(materials) ? [] : materials.data
```

to

```
let returndata = _.isEmpty(materials) ? [] : materials
```

Comment: never do `let updatedList = this.state.materials`. Use `spread operator` or `object.assign` or something. Always treat state as immutable. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5

Comment: It says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined1` :(

Comment: Updated, check again

Comment: now it just renders two blank rows in the table, no data. :(

Comment: console log your materials to check if the data is incoming.

Comment: @illiteratewriter yes, they do get returned. I think I am passing the wrong data in my render because the json structure changed?

Comment: yeah. check that and i think stuff will be sorted. :)

Comment: I think your question has been answered and you are no more having the problem you mentioned in your question.

Comment: This can set the materials out of order.